# Trigger de contagem de caracteres Oracle

Tags: trigger, oracle11g

Olá, preciso saber como criar uma `trigger` no banco de dados Oracle para que monitore um `insert` ou `update` em um campo de NCM de um produto para que não seja menor que 8 caracteres, segue exemplo abaixo:

```
IF LENGTH(UPDATING ('NCM') OR INSERTING)
            AND (:NEW.NCM < 8)
            THEN
                RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20101,'Campo NCM deve possui 8 caracteres.');
```

Comment: Qual o nome da sua tabela?

Comment: O nome da tabela é TGFPRO

Comment: Faça por check constraint https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32156650/minimum-length-constraint-on-a-column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Igual o Motta falou no comentário, ao invés de fazer uma trigger você pode fazer um check constraint. Segue abaixo as duas formas de implementar a verificação(trigger/check constraint).

**Trigger:**

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER NCM_CHECK
    BEFORE INSERT OR UPDATE ON TGFPRO
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        IF :new.Ncm < 8 THEN
            RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR (-20101,'Campo NCM deve possui 8 caracteres.');
        END IF;

END NCM_CHECK;
```

**Check Constraint:**

```
ALTER TABLE TGFPRO
ADD CONSTRAINT NCM_CHECK CHECK (LENGTHB(Ncm) < 8)
```

Espero ter ajudado, obrigado!